# Why doesn't item creation work? Fabric 1.20.1

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-fabric

I tried to create a method to conveniently register new items but when I pass `itemGroup` to ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent the program throws an error: **'modifyEntriesEvent(net.minecraft.registry.RegistryKey<net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup>)' in 'net.fabricmc.fabric .api.itemgroup.v1.ItemGroupEvents' cannot be applied to '(net.minecraft.item.ItemGroup)'**

Code:

```
private static Item registerItem(String id, Item item, ItemGroup itemGroup) {
        Item returnItem = Registry.register(Registries.ITEM, new Identifier(GoIgratiMod.MOD_ID, id), item);
        ItemGroupEvents.modifyEntriesEvent(itemGroup).register(entries -> entries.add(returnItem));
        return returnItem;
    }
```

I tried to find information on the Internet, but ready-made groups like **ItemGroups.MISC** were used everywhere

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this error...
Replacing "ItemGroup" on "RegistryKey<ItemGroup>" on 1 line